# Can you test a Teams application with cypress?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, microsoft-teams

I need to test an application within Microsoft Teams and I'd want to do that with Cypress. The problem is that I can't find a way to login into Teams using Cypress.
Things I've tried:

1. Visit [Microsoft Teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software) from Cypress and sign in from there.
   Problem: Cypress doesn't support multiple domains nor tabs within a test and clicking the *'Sign in'* button will open a new tab to this [Microsoft Login page](https://login.microsoftonline.com/)
2. Visit the [Microsoft Login page](https://login.microsoftonline.com/)  from Cypress. Problem: The url is called repeatedly and the page never loads

[image]

I've also followed [this](https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html) method but I'm not sure which keys need to be set for Teams. I've deleted all of them while logged in and it didn't logged me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with this eliostruyf.com/e2e-testing-microsoft-teams-solutions-cypress

Comment: Thanks for adding response, this will help other community members.